# FeedMe: how to update some Entries' fields with blank data?

Tags: plugin-feedme

I would like to import and update Entries using a FeedMe, based on a remote JSON file.
Sometimes, the fields are filled, sometimes not.

I would like FeedMe to update these fields if they are empty in the JSON. But currently, these blank values are skipped instead of replaced.

For special field like Date/Time field, I need a true blank value, not the current date.

Is this possible at this time? If so, how can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this a previous discussed issue even with an unmerged pull request on the Feed Me GitHub to allow this behaviour.

https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/797

You can potentially implement this without forking the entire plugin using the FeedMe field parsing events example in that issue:

https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/797#issuecomment-977858260

You'll need to add this to a module that's bootstrapped to your site, but using the field parsing events should work, until it is potentially accepted upstream as a configurable option or allows the behaviour to work.

Edit: Per more recent events. FeedMe now directly implements this solution directly, the original answer is no longer accurate, but left as in for context.

Comment: This was implemented as a setting per feed! March of 2023 https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/797#issuecomment-1474401559

Comment: @AlexKendrick Thanks! I've amended my original answer with a note, for clarity.